# CSS selector for the element without any classname or attribute

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to write a CSS selector matching the element which does not contain any attributes or class names?
For example, I have html like the following (but with tons of divs and dynamic class names) and I want to match the second div (it does not contain class)

```
<div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j x1cy8">
<div>
    <div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j x1cy8">
        <div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j n94">
            <div class="x8t9es0 x10d9sdx xo1l8bm xrohj xeuugli">$0,00</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j x1cy8zghib x19lwn94">
       <span class="x8t9es0 xw23nyj xeuugli">Helloworld.</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

P.S. Getting the div like div:nth-child(2) is not a solution.

P.P.S. Could you please advise in general why the dynamic class names are used in the development?

Comment: `P.S. Getting the div like div:nth-child(2) is not a solution.` This is false

Comment: If the classes on the elements are bound to change any time, no chance.

Comment: `div:not([class])` ?

Comment: `.xeuugli>div` . It select direct children

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can't use classes, maybe try giving it an [ID](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.php) if possible, like

```html
<div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j x1cy8">
<div id="myId">
    <div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j x1cy8">
        <div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j n94">
            <div class="x8t9es0 x10d9sdx xo1l8bm xrohj xeuugli">$0,00</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j x1cy8zghib x19lwn94">
       <span class="x8t9es0 xw23nyj xeuugli">Helloworld.</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

ad then you can select the ID via the css #id selector like so:

```css
#myId {
 /*stuff here*/
}
```

If you can't have IDs either, we could get really creative by finding a grouping element which you will swear to never use on another place, like `<section>` or `<article>`, and then you could use

```js
const elem = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];
elem.style.border = '2px solid red';
```

which returns an array of all elements with that tag name, which in our case would be the only one you need. Then you could via Javascript give it the [css you need](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).